# Selenium & Salesforce integration

Tags: java, selenium, salesforce

I am automating our salesforce application with Selenium(Java) in eclipse IDE.But not able to figure how to connect to salesforce database from selenium code through eclipse.My requirement is to query from salesforce and check case is created and delete it.
Any help is appreciated.

TIA

Comment: selenium doesn't work with database. Look at JDBC

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**Why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Are you using selenium to create the case? Soap? REST?

Comment: Refer https://www.3pillarglobal.com/insights/automated-testing-with-salesforce-and-selenium I am doing same operations using ruby but I'm using Restforce gem for that.

Answer (score 0):

(1) I wanted to make sure that Selenium is popular for UI automation of websites. 
If you are already have UI auto test developed for Salesforce and would like to check per your question - Create and Delete operations on records then use either 'Workbench' 
provided by Salesforce or use 'Salesforce Inspector' plugin.

(2) Salesforce Workbench and Salesforce Inspector - places where you can fire SOQL query and check the records

(3) Try to play around with Salesforce IDs of objects. They are unique IDs which will give you ability to open any record/object directly on browser.

For example we have Opportunity default object in Salesforce:

You can fire SOQL on 'Salesforce Workbench' or 'Salesforce Inspector' - 
select id, name from Opportunity limit 50

you will see list of IDs and open in Salesforce.

See link for more info: https://intellipaat.com/blog/tutorial/salesforce-tutorial/salesforce-workbench/

Answer (score 0):

Better to integrate RestAssured with your selenium tests. Suppose we have a scenario where we are want to update particular account in salesforce. 
We can follow below steps to automate this test using both Rest Assured and Selenium:

1. Use Rest Assured to integrate with Salesforce. You can find plenty of resources online to make this work.
2. Use rest assured to fetch the data(account) and store the name in a variable.
3. Using selenium to log in to Salesforce instance and open the account.
4. Perform the changes that are part of your test and Validate.

This is just a high level approach. We can leverage Salesforce APIs to access the data and perform modification using Rest Assured itself. But Rest Assured can also be used to fetch database values.